# Dynamically set WordPress page title

Tags: timber

When using [Timber](https://github.com/timber/timber), is it possible to dynamically set/change/edit the page title from a PHP template file? For example...

```
$context['post'] = new Timber\Post();

$context['post']->post_title = "my custom page title";
```

*It's more complicated editing the page title in the `functions.php` file, as I've see elsewhere.*

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is the purpose of this but you can use it if you want to modify `title` meta in head like that: You can just pass variable into it.

E.g.: base.twig

```
<title>

    {% if customTitle is defined %}
      {{ customTitle }}
    {% elseif wp_title %}
      {{ wp_title }}
    {% else %}
      {{ site.name }}
    {% endif %}

</title>
```

template-x.php

```
$context['customTitle'] = "Show my custom title";
```